# What does the `where {t :< Integer}` mean in the context of a function declaration in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have seen the following in other people's code, but I've never written it in my own since I didn't understand what was happening.

As an example:

`function add(x::T, y::T) where {T :< Integer}`

I am guessing that `T` is being cast as an Integer and then used to explicitly type `x` and `y`. But why not just do  `x::Int64`? Does `where {T :< Integer}` allow for any Int type like `Int32` and `Int64`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand a little on Oscar's answer:

Using `function add(x::T, y::T) where {T :< Integer}` allows you to add a **parametric method** to the function `add(x, y)`. You can read up on this in more detail in the [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/) under *Parametric Methods*.

This comes with two big advantages:
It allows you to define reasonably general methods (since in many cases the exact type of integer would not really affect the function definition). Simultaneously it allows you to restrict the call to `x, y` pairs of the same type, which can improve type stability and lead to more efficient compiled code.

Answer (score 4):

`function add(x::T, y::T) where {T :< Integer}` means that the function can be called on any 2 variables who's type is the same subtype of `Integer`. This includes things like 2 `bigInt`s, but not 1 `Int64` and 1 `Int32`. This is called Diagonal Dispatch, and is a very useful pattern.

Comment: So should all functions be written to take in the different types dynamically?

Comment: "All" is a little broad I suppose, but you can catch my drift

Comment: In general, best practice is to type your functions to accept the largest type they can run with. Note this is not accepting types dynamically, as the types allowed by these functions are determined at compile time, and if your code is type stable, dispatch will also happen at compile time.