# How to resolve "UndefVarError: T not defined" in function signature

Tags: types, julia

I am trying to run (someone else's code) that looks like

```
function f{T<:Number}(n::Int, alpha::T, beta::T)
    ...
end
```

When "using" that file I get

```
UndefVarError: T not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at [file location]:[line number of function definition above]
```

From what I've read in the documentation (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/), it looks like the syntax above is correct. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is old Julia syntax. This function should be re-written as follows, or you will need to switch to Julia 0.6 or one of the versions that came before it.

```
function f(n::Int, alpha::T, beta::T) where {T<:Number}
    ...
end
```

I ran the following on Julia 0.7 and here is what I got:

```
julia> function f{T<:Number}(n::Int, alpha::T, beta::T)
           print("Test")
       end
┌ Warning: Deprecated syntax `parametric method syntax f{T <: Number}(n::Int, alpha::T, beta::T)` around REPL[1]:2.
│ Use `f(n::Int, alpha::T, beta::T) where T <: Number` instead.
└ @ REPL[1]:2
f (generic function with 1 method)
```

[Here is the link to the general syntax for the `where` keyword.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#where)

[Here is the link to a similar StackOverflow post explaining what the `where` keyword does.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58137221/what-does-the-where-t-integer-mean-in-the-context-of-a-function-declarati)

Comment: I believe in an older version of Julia `function f{T<:Number}(n::Int, alpha::T, beta::T)` was how you created parametric methods.

Comment: Indeed! Updated with the output from Julia 0.7!

Comment: I believe that syntax is only valid on 0.6 and before actually - not 0.7